# how can i stream with audio an ip camera like Axis on web?

Tags: html, streaming, ip-camera

how can i stream with audio an ip camera like Axis on web ?
This one use a direct connection between camera & client but is limited to 20 connections , use too much bandwith , works only for IE

```
<form name="test">
  <input id="ip" type="input" size="10" value="192.168.X.X">
  <input type="button" name="Play" value="Play" onClick="OnPlay(); return false;">
</form>
<object id="Player" height="480" width="640" border="1" classid="CLSID:745395C8-D0E1-4227-8586-624CA9A10A8D">
  AXIS Media Control (SDK) for Internet Explorer is not installed or failed to initialize.
  <param name="AutoStart" value="0">
  <param name="UIMode" value="none">
  <param name="MediaType" value="h264">
  <param name="VideoRenderer" value="65536"> <!-- Use Enhanced Video Renderer for best performance -->
  <param name="NetworkTimeout" value="5000"><!-- use this param if you want to change the network timeout -->
  <param name="MediaUsername" value=""><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
  <param name="MediaPassword" value=""><!-- this param only necessary if restricted access is enabled -->
  <param name="MediaURL" value="axrtpu://myServer/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264"><!-- your media url goes here -->
</object>

<script language="JavaScript">
    document.Player.EnableContextMenu = true;
    document.Player.StretchToFit = true;
    document.Player.MaintainAspectRatio = true;
function OnPlay()
{
  try
  {
    var server = document.getElementById('ip').value;
    // return values from AMC methods are handled as exceptions in JavaScript
    document.Player.Stop();
    document.Player.MediaURL = "axrtsphttp://" + server + "/axis-media/media.amp?videocodec=h264";
    document.Player.Play();
  }
  catch(e){}
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" for="Player" event="OnError(theError, theMsg)"> alert(theError + ' ' + theMsg); </script>
```

I'd like to use just one connection (one flow) from a server which is visible by anyone visits the site